# Restore previous value into an input field when Esc key is pressed - Angular

Tags: angular

I have an array

```
public languages: any[] = [{Name: "English", IsDefault: true},
                        {Name: "Russian", IsDefault: false},
                        {Name: "Spanish", IsDefault: false}];
```

in .ts file
and in .html file I have displayed those language name's into an input field as

```
  <ul class="list-style-type">
              <li class="li-list-style-type"  *ngFor="let language of languages; let i=index" id="language-item-{{i}}">
                <mat-form-field class="mat-input-style">
                  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="language.Name" (keyup.esc)="setPreviousValue($event,language,i)">
                </mat-form-field>
```

I can edit language name from the input field. If I press Esc key, then I need to restore the previous value of that input.
I tried by writing the following function in the .ts file.

```
public setPreviousValue(event,language,index)
{
  language.Name=this.languages[index].Name;
}
```

But I am getting newly typed name instead of previous one.
I believe it is because of the use of [(ngModel)] in the .html file.
Tried to create a local variable for storing the Name. But could not do that.
Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: What is the result when you do that inside your setPreviousValue method -> language.Name=this.languages[index-1].Name

Comment: That will give the Name of the previous item. I need the previous Name of the current item. That is if I edit 'Russian' as 'French' and then Esc key is pressed, then it should be 'Russian'.

Answer (score 2):

`[(ngModel)]="language.Name"` binds `language.Name` to the value the user types, updating as they type, so your `setPreviousValue` function sets the variable to its own current value. You will need to store the original name separately. One option is to set a `PreviousName` property on each entry in `languages`. When you set this value depends on exactly what you mean by "previous value". If it's the value when the form loads, you can set it in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook eg.

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.languages = this.languages.map(l => {...l, PreviousName: l.Name});
}
public setPreviousValue(event,language,index)
{
  language.Name=this.languages[index].PreviousName;
}
```

Be careful when submitting the form though, or you'll end up trying to save `PreviousName` to the database.

Comment: I agree with you, it will depend on what does he mean by previous value. It can be when you the user clicks out of the input, or when the user switches to the next input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that "esc" restore the previous value (NOT the original value, I want to say that if you change English to Dustch and Dustch to Green+ESC, you'll get Dustch), you can use [ngModel] and update the value in (blur). In (keyup.esc) equal the value to the model. For this, it's necesary using a reference variable

```
<ul class="list-style-type">
    <li class="li-list-style-type" 
       *ngFor="let language of languages; let i=index" 
       id="language-item-{{i}}">
        <mat-form-field class="mat-input-style">
            <input matInput #input name="language+{{i}}" 
            [ngModel]="language.Name" 
            (blur)="language.Name=input.value" 
            (keyup.esc)="input.value=language.Name">
    </mat-form-field>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-22rrgj?file=app/input-overview-example.html)